# Call an ES6 Arrow function from another function in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an Arrow function to show the validation of form fields as:

```
showValidation = (field) => () => {
    console.log(field);
    this.setFieldState(field, {showValidation: true});

  }
```

Now I want to call to function from another function that loops through all the form entries as:

```
showAllValidations() {
    let self = this;
    for (let field of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']) {
      console.log(field);
      self.showValidation(field);
    }
  }
```

The `console.log(field)` in `showValidation` doesn't print anything  while the `console.log(field)` in `showAllValidations()` displays all the fields so I assume that it is not getting called. I am new to ReactJs & ES6 and stuck with this problem for a long time.

Comment: Try invoking the function returned from arrow function like this self.showValidation(field)();

Comment: What's with the `thunk` chained on the end? If you have reason for it to be there, then you'll call `showValidation` like this. `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'].map(field => this.showValidation(field)())`

Comment: @azium: In fact the OP didn't ask a question at all :-) But the duplicate explains everything he needs to solve his problem, doesn't it?